# Is there a way to show that polar equations $r=a\sec\theta+b $ and $r=a\sec\theta-b$ yield the same graph?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates

I'd be glad if you show me some light here.

It's stated all over the net that the Nicomedes Conchoid polar equation is $r=a\sec\theta + b $.

I'm trying to figure out that equation by locus points but in my construction I get $r=a\sec\theta \pm b$ (there's two points in the intersection of the circle)

While graphing the equations apart with the plus sign and the minus sign, I get the same graph (the sign just seems to indicate the direction of the trace).

Here's the question:

> Is there a way to show that $r=a\sec\theta + b $ and $r=a\sec\theta - b $ are the same graph?

Maybe doing some algebra to show that by cosine properties they trace the same path? So far, I got nothing trying that (is that even possible?)

I could try to show that both equations get the same cartesian equation, but is that enough to say that there's no problem if we leave that minus sign behind?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you consider that "both equations get the same cartesian equation" would mean that you have a consistent cartesian equation from which to graph, meaning that the graphs would be the same, then this would answer your primary question, right?

Comment: $ \ r = -b \ $ at $ \  \theta \pm \pi \ $ is the same as $ \ r = b \ $ at $ \ \theta \ $ and $ \ \sec(\theta \pm  \pi) \  =  \ -\sec \theta  \ \ . $  Half a cycle through the angles for $ \ a\sec \theta + b \ $ will trace the other half not covered by $ \ a\sec \theta - b \ $ ; taking a full cycle of $ \ 0 \ $ to $ \ 2 \pi \ $ produces the same curve for both equations.

Comment: Another way of seeing this is that we can write $$ r \ = \ \frac{a}{\cos \theta} \ \pm b \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ r \cos \theta \ \ = \ \ a \ \pm \ b \cos \theta \ \rightarrow \ x \ \ = \ \ a \ \pm \ b \cos \theta \ \ . $$   This amounts to the same curve being traced over opposite halves of the cycle of angles.

Comment: Let $r(\theta)=a\sec\theta+b$. Then 
$$r(\theta+\pi)=a\sec(\theta+\pi)+b=-a\sec\theta+b=-(a\sec\theta-b)$$
In polar coordinates, a negative radius is plotted "backwards" through the origin; ie, we plot the *positive* radius in the *opposite* direction. But direction angle opposite $\theta+\pi$ is just $\theta$, so we have
$$r(\theta)=+(a\sec\theta-b)$$
So, in direction $\theta$ we plot two points: the "regular point" at distance $a\sec\theta+b$, and the "backwards point from the opposite direction" at distance $a\sec\theta-b$. Effectively, $r(\theta)=a\sec\theta\pm b$.

Comment: I'd have never come up with those ideas. Yes, @boojum, I should have specified the interval for theta, I meant for [0, 2pi] for the graphs to be the same.

Comment: Thank you @Blue !